# More about EOF in loop condition

Tags: c++

Okay, when I saw this thread: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

I read the answers but I really didn't understand what is wrong in this, maybe because I don't have much experience in c++ but my code works exactly the way it's supposed to.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    string text, search;
    int offset;
    cout << "Enter a word: "; cin >> search;
    file.open("Find.txt");
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (!file.eof()) {
            file >> text;
            offset = text.find(search, 0);
            if (offset != string::npos) {
                cout << text << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error!";
        return 0;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

I enter in a word, and it searches for it in a text file, and I had zero problems using that. So, when is this condition considered wrong?

Comment: Because `file >> text;` can fail and you never know it because you never check it. You would thus march on and use whatever crap happens to be in `text`, potentially the last time is succeeded.Did you try searching for the *last* word in your file?

Comment: Yes, it outputs it normally

Answer (score 1):

I won't repeat everything said in that thread; that would be a waste of time.

If you did this:

```
    while (!file.eof()) {
        file >> text;
        // offset = text.find(search, 0);
        // if (offset != string::npos) {
            cout << "Text: " << text << endl;
        // }
    }
```

… then you would see the problem: an "extra" loop iteration every single time you run the program, with `text` having whatever value it had for the previous iteration.

Since your output is conditional on the result of searching in `text` for a specific substring, *if* that search on the final line of input will fail, you get away with it! However, if the last line matches, you'll again see the problem.

This manner of loop-input does not *always* cause a bug. That's why the linked Q&A says it's "almost certainly wrong". Sometimes the logic inside the loop is specifically designed to work correctly; other times it *just so happens* to avoid the bug, as yours does.

The correct code is:

```
while (file >> text)
{
    offset = text.find(search, 0);
    if (offset != string::npos) {
        cout << text << endl;
    }
}
```